# How to apply SAML authenticator to an already created GoodData user account?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, openam, gooddata

I would like to know how to apply SAML authenticator to an already created certain GoodData user account in order to allow it to pass-through into GoodData? For SAMLauthentication service, I am considering to set up Open AM service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Open AM service, you would need to [contact Support](http://mailto%3asupport@gooddata.com), because GoodData Platform doesn't support Open AM natively. You should provide some key information and GoodData will need to implement it on its end.

For existing user provisioning - for changing the user SSO Provider parameter over the API, the user has to be created in a specific domain. You are not allowed to change a domain for a user by yourself (ask support if you need this). Otherwise, if you create user in the domain you can later change SSO Provider for them because your domain is controlled by your domain admin account.

Comment: Are supported SAML authentication providers OKTA and Fluig only?

Comment: I mean natively supported.

Comment: Yes. Only Okta, Fluig natively but we are ready to add others. We are also able to set up Active Directory, but it is custom for each client. Feel free to contact Support directly for details. Thanks.